# Is there a way to make 2 canvases with an image on both of the canvases?

Tags: html, image, canvas

So I want a canvas with an image on both of them.

Here is the canvas code I currently have

```
<img id="Man2" width="0" height="0" src="Man2.PNG" alt="Man2">

<canvas id="myCanvas1" width="600" height="450" style="border:1px solid grey;"></canvas>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
  const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas1");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const img = document.getElementById("Man2");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
};
</script>
```

Is there a way to replicate this?

I tried to duplicate the code, by changing the source, image id, alt, canvas id. Here is what I did.

```
<img id="Evil" width="0" height="0" src="Evil.png" alt="Evil">

<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="600" height="450" style="border:1px solid grey;"></canvas>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
  const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas2");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const img = document.getElementById("Evil");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
};
</script>
```

It did make another canvas with an image. But it completely removed the image on the other canvas.

Here is a few pictures on what I mean.

[image: Before code]

[image: After code]

Comment: It would help if you provided the code which attempts to put two images onto two canvases. If you just replicated the above code, it loos like the `window.onload = .....` part is catching you out. If you assigned something to that twice, only the second would end up doing something, since it would overwrite the first instance something was assigned. If this *is* what's going on, consider looking into `.addEventListener` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: The canvas code provided above is attempting to put the image on the canvas.

Comment: Indeed. A better choice of words may have been "if you provide *all* of the code....." Since as I mentioned, the way these two snippets are being used together could be (read: seems likely to be) what's causing the problem.

Comment: Like the whole, code that I currently have?

Comment: I figured it out. The .addEventListener helped a lot. I made a variable for the ctx, img and the canvas. Then I called the img by the event listener.